# What can this circuit be useful for?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, homework

[image]

I have calculated the boolean functions for `r`  and `f`:

`f` = (¬s1 ∧ s0) ∨ (s1 ∧ ¬s0).

`r` = ¬ (s0 ∧ s1 ∧ s2 ∧ s3).

Do you have an idea what an application for this circuit might be? I don't know where we would use it.

Comment: sequence generator?

Comment: Now what would this site become if everyone started posting random circuits asking if this or that were useful. This can't be encouraged plus, your question is soliciting opinions hence I'm voting to close it.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not asking if it's useful, I'm asking what a possible application of such a circuit might be.

Comment: @J.Hodge Count me in! There are four of us now.

Comment: Last nail in the coffin. This circuit didn't fall out of the sky, it came from somewhere. That somewhere should explain what it does and how it us useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower path `f` creates an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) that cycles through all 15 nonzero states before repeating.

The upper path `r` creates a reset signal that makes sure the LFSR doesn't get stuck in the all-zeros state.<sup>1</sup> In normal operation, this path is never activated.

A short LFSR like this is not particularly useful for "random" numbers (a common application of longer LFSRs), but it can be useful as a sequence generator, since it's much simpler than a binary counter.

---

<sup>1</sup> BTW, your analysis is incorrect. That's a NOR gate, not a NAND gate.

Comment: I really don't like that you vote to close a question _and_ answer it. It's like you think it's good enough for _you_ to answer, but you want to close it for everyone else.

Comment: @pipe: I don't see the problem here. You had the same opportunity to answer that I did, yet you both downvoted and voted to close. I was mainly reacting to the comments on the question, most of whom seemed to have no clue. I had a factual answer, so I provided it. Even though the question is not suitable for the site, at least the OP goes away satisfied, softening the impact of rejection. Aren't we supposed to be making everyone "feel welcome" here?

Comment: Voting to close a question isn't making anyone feel welcome. Preventing _other_ users on the site from getting upvotes while adding your own answer and then closing the question is definitely not making anyone here feel welcome.